# Customize in list of spgroup sharepoint programmatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I want to add column (Lookup Field) to list of SharePoint Group programmatically. 
Like this image from administration.

[image: From Sp Group Page > Setting > List Setting]

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the SPList object through the ID of the list. When you click on the link your marked in red you will see the GUID in the Url.

Copy this ID and use this code to obtain the SPList object.

```
SPList list = web.Lists.GetList(new Guid("<your copied ID>"), false);
Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
```

You can then use the SPList object to add columns like any other normal list (through the Fields property which returns an SPFieldCollection). Use list.Fields.Add() to add existing columns.

You might have to create the site columns first (or use an overload method to create it at once)

See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa540133%28v=office.14%29.aspx